# Block requests based on hostname

Tags: nginx, performance

Has anyone used this module in their Nginx setup?

If yes, I would like to know about it's performance. How much would it affect the response time etc.

https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns

The module basically does a reverse dns lookup to get the hostname before processing a request.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Edit: @Kromey, @MichaelHampton, thanks for the time and replies. Here is the reason for the question:

**Scenario:**

I have a website set up which contains a couple of forms. Whenever someone fills up the form, I get a mail with the form details.

**Problem:**

For the past couple of days, someone has been submitting the forms through a bot. I have been getting a few thousand mails a day. All the mails have been coming through this host:

205.47.89.110.broad.pt.fj.dynamic.163data.com.cn.

The ip at the start keeps changing, but, the host name after that is the same.(I did a nslookup on the ips for the hostname).

As you can probably guess, I am not too happy about this.

**Solutions I have looked at:**

1. Captcha - Don't want to implement this since it is basically extra work for users
2. Hidden field - Include a hidden field that a normal user cannot see. Since a bot usually fills out all the fields in a form, I can check if this field is filled and reject the details if the field contains any value - See next point for the reason I don't want to implement this.
3. Measure time between the point where the user starts filling the form and the point where user submits a form. Since bots do this really quickly, reject the request if the measured time is below a certain threshold - I want to reject the request even before the user has access to the form. That is, at the Nginx layer itself. Basically, I am trying to minimize the bandwidth and resource consumption on the server.

So, the solution I am leaning towards is to block based on hostname. Feel free to convince me otherwise. I am open to suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: It would be as slow as the slowest DNS server that you have to query to resolve a name.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to ask about what you want to *accomplish*; as @MichaelHampton implies this is going to have highly variable performance (in just a couple of reverse DNS test queries I got nigh-immediate responses, and responses taking nearly 2 full seconds -- I know that doesn't sound like a lot, but when you're doing it on every single request...), but if we know what you're after we may be able to help you get there with a better solution.

Comment: Why don't you just look up the IP address block in [whois](http://www.apnic.net/apnic-info/whois_search) and block that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Can you please elaborate? I did a whois look up for one of the ips on the link provided and ended up with [this result.](http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=205.47.89.110?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2)



Are you asking me to block the entire block 205.0.0.0 - 205.55.255.255 of IP Adresses?

Comment: No, of course not. You entered the wrong IP address. Use the actual IP address.

Comment: Ah yes, My bad. Got the IP address from the logs and all the IPs point here: 27.148.0.0 - 27.151.255.255

Will be trying it out. Thanks for all the help.